# Why is that constantly animating UIActivityIndicator won't block main thread?

Tags: ios, animation, uiactivityindicatorview

We all show activity indicator while some lengthy operation is happening in background. Though the activity indicator shows a constantly rotating wheel it won't burden the main thread, because other `UIComponents` in the same screen still react to the touches.

**What I think I know:**

I know all touch events are handled by main thread, and main Queue is being used to queue the events. Considering main queue is Serialized queue and only one task at a time can run at any given point in time, alley touch events should get queued up in main queue, while my main thread is busy in refreshing the screen/calling drawrect of UIActivityIndicator.

**Study:**

I have looked into the code of third party activity indicators. Most of them use `CABasicAnimation` and call repeat always on animation. While few work directly use NSTimer to repeatedly call `drawrect` with a small delay. Their code works because there is a small delay in calling `drawrect` and the method `drawrect` in itself is light weight.

None of  it won't take the loads off the main thread but rather they carefully place load on main thread enough to keep their animation going yet keeping main thread free to handle touch events

**What I want to know:**

1 - Is this strategy to implement activity indicator is correct? or statement like this

```
self.timer =[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self
selector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

in one of the third party activity indicator that I saw has any special effect?

2 - If I run CABasicAnimation/transaction and repeat the animation forever will it have any special effects on the load of main thread compared to repeatedly calling setNeedsDispaly/drawrect manually?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by calling `setNeedsDisplay` periodically? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Assume I have a image which I want to rotate/load different image based on progress amount / any progress animation I wanna perform most of the third party frameworks handle these thing in drawRect method of UIView and in order to trigger drawRect they call setNeedsDisplay

Comment: @downvoter : Just because u don't understand the question does not make u eligible to down vote the question. If u cant understand ask me, if u know answer comment here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it will help to implement your own activity indicator, but the system one `UIActivitiyIndicatorView` is just a `UIImageView` with an array of 12 images that replace each other over time.

[image: UIActivityIndicatorView]

Apple made a pretty neat trick by making their spinner discrete. It allowed them to have a simple implementation that doesn't create any computational load on CPU.

**UPD**

Returning to the things you want to know:
*1* - It's not, because implementing manual frame drawing in `drawRect` is fully done by CPU. And *2* - I can't say for sure, but if one believes what Apple says in documentation and videos about `Core Animation` it is heavily optimised and runs on `Metal` or at least `OpenGL` underneath, so leverages power of GPU.

Comment: I have used this trick and infect using CADisplayLink to refresh the page rather than using NSTimer is neat trick. All am trying to understand is that using CADisplayLink/NSTimer to call setNeedsDisplay/drawRect ultimately adds burden on main thread only no? So it all boil downs to what we have in drawRect or any method of ours which actually does animation. If the method has something computationally heavy then UI will hang correct? I was wondering is there way out like using Runloop where I won't end up burdening main thread. I believe there is no other way now

Comment: thanks for replaying :) much appreciated :) I agree with image replacing trick hence +1. As it only partially answers my question am gonna wait a little longer for better answer before accepting urs :)

Comment: No problem. I've added a bit of clarification, maybe it will help in your research. Good luck!

Comment: I guess u are correct, checked MBProgressHUD code, they are making use of CADisplayLink to refresh the UI while using CGAffineTransform :) that means they are trying to leverage the GPU while using CADisplayLink to do it efficiently :) Hence accepting ur answer :) Thanks a lot